# converting vector into a MxN matrix

Tags: python

How can one convert a vector into a MxN matrix?
I have tried with reshape but cant quite figure it out.

```
a vector A 
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
b = 3
C = 5

New matrix 
M = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [6,7,8,9,10],
     [11,12,13,14,15]]
```

Comment: Using numpy, `A.reshape(b, C)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with using numpy :

```
import numpy as np 

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
b = 3
C = 5

x = np.reshape(A, (b, C))

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
C = 5

M = [A[i:i + C] for i in range(0, len(A), C)]
print (M)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```